# Swift counting from Label in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

I asked a similar question but I need help

I have `UIViewController` which contains `UITableView`, `UILabel` under a table to display total price.

In `UITableViewCell` I have `UIImage` to display photo, `UILabel` to display the quantity,  + - `UIButton` 's and `UILabel` to display price.

I take the data from `UserDefaults`

I want to display in total `UILabel` total price form quantity x price 
with the amount of each `UITableViewCell`

When pressing the + or - `UIButton` need to change `UILabel` with quantity

Code from `UIViewController` :

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TetTableViewCell    
        var item = loadedCart[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLbl?.text = item["name"] //as? String
        cell.priceLbl.text = item["price"] //as? String
        cell.qntUserDef = Int(item["qty"]!)!
        updateTotal()
  return cell
  }

   func updateTotal() {
   for item in loadedCart {

        var qnt = item["qty"] ?? ""
        var price = item["price"] ?? ""

        let val = qnt.components(separatedBy: "").compactMap { Int($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) }
        var sum = val.reduce(0, +)
        print("sum\(sum)")

        let prrr = price.components(separatedBy: "").compactMap { Int($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) }
        let sumpri = prrr.reduce(0, +)
        print("sumpri\(sumpri)")


        qntUser += (sum * sumpri) ?? 0


        if item["qty"] == nil {
            self.totalSummLbl.text = "\(0)"
        }

        if item["qty"]?.count == 0 {
            totalSummLbl.text = "\(0)"
            print("total\(totalSummLbl.text)")
        } else {
            totalSummLbl.text = "\(qntUser)"

        }
    }

}
```

And code from `UITableViewCell`:

```
var lCart = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "car") as? [[String: String]] ?? []

var qntUserDef: Int = 0
 @IBAction func plusBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
 for item in lCart {
        qntLbl.text = item["qty"]
    }
    qntUserDef += 1
    qntLbl.text = "\(qntUserDef)"
    print("tettttt-\(qntUserDef)")
 }
```

By this I have achieved that quantity `UILabel` changed, but when I go in another and back -  don't save and doesn't show new quantity and sum in total `UILabel`

How can I change the code to resave data to `UserDefaults` and display it in total `UILabel` when pressing the + or -?

To Tai Ho answer :

VC code:

```
Class : 

 weak var delegate: TestTableViewCell?

  extension TestTABLEVC: OrderTableViewCellDelegate {
 func plusButtonPressed(_ cell: TestTableViewCell) {
    let indexPath = self.tableViewT.indexPath(for: cell)
    var item = loadedCart[(indexPath?.row)!]
        item["qty"] = "\(cell.qntUserDef)"

        // write the data back to user default
    var oldValue = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "car")
    item.updateValue(cell.qntLbl.text!, forKey: "qty")

        // reload this cell
        self.tableViewT.beginUpdates()
    self.tableViewT.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
    self.tableViewT.endUpdates()
}
}
```

Code from `TableViewCell` :

```
import UIKit

  protocol OrderTableViewCellDelegate: class {
   func plusButtonPressed(_ cell: TestTableViewCell)

   }

 class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

weak var delegate: OrderTableViewCellDelegate?
 @IBAction func plusBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.plusButtonPressed(self)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you did is just change the in-memory vars. You need to write these new values back to the user defaults to have it saved.

You can do this in the `func plusBtn(_ sender: UIButton)`, delegate it to the ViewController and do the job there.
And in the `viewWillAppear`, remember to reload the data from user default, the refresh the table view.

There are some tips:
- Create a model class to hold the data. For example:

```
class Order {
  var name: String
  var price: Double
  var quantity: Int
}
```

- give the tableviewcell a delegate:

protocol OrderTableViewCellDelegate: class {
   func plusButtonPressed(_ cell: OrderTableViewCell)
}

in the table view cell class,

```
class OrderTableView {
   ... your view outlets go here

   weak delegate: OrderTableViewCellDelegate?

   @IBAction func plusBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
       delegate?.plusButtonPressed(self)
   }
}
```

- In the view controller, remember to implement the OrderTableViewCellDelegate.

```
extension class CartViewController: OrderTableViewCellDelegate {
     override func plusButtonPressed(_ cell: OrderTableViewCell) {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        let item = self.items[indexPath.row]
        item.quantity += 1

        // write the data back to user default
        ....

        // reload this cell
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.reloadCellAtIndexes([indexPath], animation: .automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
     }
}
```

in the `viewWillAppear`,

```
func viewWillAppear(_animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //reload the data from user default
    self.items = read and parse the data from user default to a list of Order models
    //reload the table view
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**UPDATED: Set the delegate for the cell.**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OderCell", for: indexPath)

        // configure your cell

        // IMPORTANT: set the cell's delegate to this VC
        cell.delegate = self.

        return cell
}
```

Comment: Hi, did I understand correctly? 
 TableViewCell class:
 import UIKit

protocol OrderTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func plusButtonPressed(_ cell: TestTableViewCell)
}
 weak var delegate: OrderTableViewCellDelegate?
   @IBAction func plusBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
 delegate?.plusButtonPressed(self)
  }

Comment: In ViewCintroller Class :
      weak var delegate: TestTableViewCell?
extension  TestTABLEVC: OrderTableViewCellDelegate {
     func plusButtonPressed(_ cell: TestTableViewCell) {
        let indexPath = self.tableViewT.indexPath(for: cell)
        var item = self.loadedCart[(indexPath?.row)!]
            var oldValue = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "car")
        item.updateValue((delegate?.qntLbl.text)!, forKey: "qty")
            self.tableViewT.beginUpdates()
        self.tableViewT.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
        self.tableViewT.endUpdates()      ?

Comment: Can you edit your comments with the code formatted? And have to assign the cell's delegate to the VC as well. `cell.delegate = self` in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellAtIndexPath)` method

Comment: Im add formatted code in question and add in cellAtIndexPath  `cell.delegate = self`

Comment: I updated my answer. You don't need to create the delegate in the VC. Look at the code added for details.